# Prove that the matrix is hermitian

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

Prove that if $a*b\ge0$ and $|a|=|b|$ then the matrix below is Hermitian. Where $a,b are possibly complex numbers.

\begin{bmatrix} 1&a&0\\b&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}

I know that for this to hold I must prove only that $ a = \bar{b}$. But I am having trouble proving that.  Please help.

Comment: What does $*$ mean?  Is it multiplication?  If so, then you're saying that $ab \in \Bbb R^+ \cup \{0\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
|a|=|b|=\rho \Rightarrow a=\rho e^{i\alpha} \quad \land \quad b=\rho e^{i\beta}
$$
and:
$$
ab\ge 0 \Rightarrow \rho^2 e^{i(\alpha+\beta)} \ge 0 \Rightarrow \alpha+\beta=0 
$$

Comment: got it... thanks

Comment: you're welcome. don't forget to accept if you want:)

Comment: sorry... i forgot that totally